# Importing a function that uses "import * as x" as default argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I'm looking at some javascript code that seems like it could work, but it doesn't. In one module there's a function imports a bundle of helpers to curry/decorate(?) its own dictionary of functions to export, but assigns it as a default value, instead of using the import directly:

```
import * as curry from './curry-module.js'

export function example(curry = curry) {
  return {
    foo: (args) => curry.foo(args),
    bar: (args) => curry.bar(args),
  }
}
```

The motivation here seems to be to allow you to either provide it a different currying bundle when mocking or test, or let it by default use the real curry functions.

But if I import this function into another module and call it without arguments, the default value isn't used and undefined errors crop up:

```
import { example } from './example-module.js'

// within example(), curry is undefined and throws an error
example().foo(someArgs)
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, the issue was having the import and the argument variables named the same. It was creating ambiguity for the transpiler and I ended up with ES5 code like this:

```
var curry = require('./curry-module.js')

function example() {
    var curry = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined 
      ? arguments[0] 
      : curry;
}
```

So `curry` was being redeclared, making it undefined, and then assigned to itself when no arguments were passed in. And the `curry` in the outer scope is never used.

Changing the function's argument name to be different than the import name is the fix here.

Comment: This is not a problem with the transpiler, it would also be broken without the transpiler. It's the same if you did `var foo = foo;`.

Comment: i don't think you understand what i'm saying. it is actually an issue with the transpiler and the way it picks variable names and declares interop variables when moving from ES6 to ES5. both curries are distinct and the transpiler recognizes that, but then the interop assignment creates the redundant assignment. it's something that won't show up in a compressed bundles with the transpiler also uglifies variable names.

Comment: Yes and no. See the duplicate question. If you run this code in your browser's console: `var foo = 42; function bar(foo=foo) { console.log(foo); }; bar();` you will see that it doesn't work either (though instead of silently failing, you are getting an error).

Comment: i never said anything about a silent error. and i'm not talking about ES5 behavior here, but a valid ES6 construct that causes a problem for an ES5 transpile/interop step.

Comment: It's not valid (as in runnable) ES6, that's my whole point. See the duplicate question.

Comment: i think you meant to link more directly that default params are managed from within their function's scope and not the outer scope?

Comment: Kind of. If default parameters are present then a new scope for parameters is created within which the default argument values are resolved. I.e. the `foo` on the right hand side of the assignment resolves to the uninitialized parameter `foo` and therefore throwing an error. The error doesn't happen in the transpiled version though, it just defaults to `undefined` because of `var`. Hence me saying that it's partially a transpiler issue, but your code would not run in an ES6 environment either. And the duplicate question explains that.